# XML export with Excel vba code

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I would like to ask if it's somehow possible to include some [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code in an XML file?

After an export of my excel file to xml I cannot see it.

My goal is to create excel with macros from xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting confused between saving an `XML Data` file and an `Excel Add-In` (you may have seen this called an `XML Add-in`).

By using `Save As` and selecting the `XML Data` file type, Excel will produce an XML file with the data contained only on your worksheets and so no VBA is saved. An `Excel Add-In` though is a file containing macro information so you can quite easily add the macros it contains to another installation of Excel, I believe this is the goal you are trying to achieve.

[This webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx) helped me a lot when I first learned how to create add-ins, and it also includes information on creating custom ribbon UI's for your macros; [And this webpage](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-or-remove-add-ins-64d3d147-98fb-4b82-8833-709d54e3ace1) contains instructions on adding / removing Add-ins.

Comment: Unfortunately this excel add-in is not working with 64-bit.

Comment: @Acla can you elaborate on that with a specific error message? I'm guessing that your specific macro is 32-bit and you're trying to add it to a 64-bit installation of Excel? Try adding `PtrSafe` after any `Declare` statements